# Managing DI objects without frameworks

Tags: java, object, dependency-injection

Is there any good way to manage objects via DI in Java (8+) without using additional frameworks (Like Spring)? Any design patterns or way of coding to achieve it without downloading any dependencies?

Comment: What is the problem u are facing with spring framework ?

Comment: I do not have any problem with spring neither spring boot :) I was just curious, If I can create app managing objects in plain Java, for example if the requirement is - Only Java SE

Comment: Practicing DI without the use of a DI library is a common practice called [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You could write your own CDI without a Framework.

To have the annotations without an implementation is common in Java, another candidate is the EntityManager. The EntityManager is available in Java but not implemented.

This is part of the principle of Inversion of Control (ioc). Where a underlying abstraction (jboss) controls the DI.

You should not use CDI without a service-abstraction.

Comment: So is there a different way to manage objects apart from cdi?

Comment: @Thamiar Question is unclear. DI without DI? What else is left?

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding that applying the Dependency Injection pattern requires the use of a library; it does not. It is possible to do so and in some cases composing your object graphs by hand (while still applying DI and loose coupling) is preferred.

Comment: @PeterRader I meant without framework. Make it as a DI pattern. If you cannot manage objects using DI pattern, what are the other options?

Comment: @Steven What do you mean with "library", the jar-files? The JVM can technically load jar-files and .class-files! Even if it is possible to load applications from .class-files only I think to change the technique how classes are load into the JVM does help in this conceptional question.

Comment: @Thamiar A DI/IOC/CDI is always a abstraction providing generic functionality. So it is a "framework"! Must it be a 3rd party framework? No! Must it be in a seperate jar-file? No! What patterns are required in order to build a custom DI framework? A classpath-scanner, the singleton-pattern and the factory-method-pattern and reflection.

Comment: @PeterRader: [DIPP&P](https://manning.com/seemann2) defines a "DI Container" as "A software library that provides DI functionality and automates many of the tasks involved in Object Composition, Interception, and Lifetime Management. It's an engine that resolves and manages object graphs. See chapter 12." I use the term "DI library" and "DI Container" interchangingly. Using this definition, the JVM is not a DI Container, but Spring and CDI are. Just like .NET is not a DI Container, but Autofac, MS.DI, and Simple Injector are.

Comment: @Steven Hm. If you use library and DI Container interchangingly someone could read your sentence like *It is a common misunderstanding that applying the Dependency Injection pattern requires the use of a DI Container; it does not*. Right?

Comment: Hi @Peter, I'm unsure I understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Steven I repeated what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You do not need to use DI container such as Spring. You can use manual injection. The way to do that would be to use you main method as the composition root of your application and construct your object graph there.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application(
        new FooService(new FooRepository()),
        new BarService(new BarRepository())
        // ... Anything else your application needs
    ).run();
}
```

Comment: Januson, How you would deal with Object Memory management and Object lifecycle ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by memory management. For the lifecycle, lets say you want something like a request scope. So you have an object representing your request. Everything in it is basically request scoped as it goes out of scope together with the request.

Comment: "Januson, How you would deal with Object Memory management and Object lifecycle?" There is actually [a complete book on this topic](https://manning.com/seemann2). It discusses Object Composition and Lifetime Management in the context of DI and shows examples how to achieve this using [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Spring or a similar solution, you would have to maintain your own set of dependencies. I would make a Singleton class on which you can register dependencies or request them, looking like this:

```
public final class DependencyProvider {

   private final ConcurrentMap<Class<?>, Object> dependencies = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

   private DependencyProvider() {
   }

   public <T> T registerDependency(Class<T> type, T instance) {
       Object oldInstance = dependencies.putIfAbsent(type, instance);
       return oldInstance != null ? type.cast(oldInstance) : instance;
   }

   public <T> T getDependency(Class<T> type) {
       return type.cast(dependencies.get(type));
   }

   public static DependencyProvider getInstance() {
       return PROVIDER.instance;
   }

   private static class PROVIDER {
      private static final DependencyProvider instance = new DependencyProvider();
   }
}
```

Starting from the provided code, you can extend it to search for classes which have a certain annotation and try to use reflection to instantiate them. Obviously, it would be easier if the annotated classes would have only no-args constructors or else you would have to make sure you don't have issues like circular dependencies. You could make a graph to decide the order in which you should instantiate classes.

Another solution would be to have a dependency loader in which you build the dependencies in the correct order, but in that case you have to make sure to always include any new services.

Answer (score 0):

> I was just curious, If I can create app managing objects in plain Java, for example if the requirement is - Only Java SE

Yes, it is possible - [ServiceLoader](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-dependency-injection-wi) is a little known framework built into the JDK that allows you to do very basic DI. It's nowhere near as slick or powerful as "proper" DI frameworks, but in brief, the process is as follows:

- Create a `META-INF/services` folder
- Create a file in that folder with the same (fully qualified) name as your interface
- Write the (fully qualified) name of the implementation to the first line of the above file
- Use `java.util.ServiceLoader.load(MyInterface.class)` to load the implementation of the above interface.

It works in Java 6+, so it's not a particularly new feature. Compatibility shouldn't be an issue.

That being said, it's so obscure I wouldn't use it. Spring is near enough ubiquitous these days; I can't think of a practical situation where I'd use the above in its place.

Comment: Good catch. Did not know this either.